Why use tpm in TSS. java project The EvictControl() method runs incorrectly with the message: {NO_SESSIONS} ？
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Tpm tpm = TpmFactory.platformTpm();
        byte[] nullVec = new byte[0];
        byte[] aesKey = Helpers.RandomBytes(16);
        TPMT_PUBLIC aesTemplate = new TPMT_PUBLIC(TPM_ALG_ID.SHA256, new TPMA_OBJECT(new TPMA_OBJECT[]{TPMA_OBJECT.decrypt, TPMA_OBJECT.sign, TPMA_OBJECT.fixedParent, TPMA_OBJECT.fixedTPM, TPMA_OBJECT.userWithAuth}), new byte[0], new TPMS_SYMCIPHER_PARMS(new TPMT_SYM_DEF_OBJECT(TPM_ALG_ID.AES, 128, TPM_ALG_ID.CFB)), new TPM2B_DIGEST_SYMCIPHER());
        TPMS_SENSITIVE_CREATE sensCreate = new TPMS_SENSITIVE_CREATE(nullVec, aesKey);
        CreatePrimaryResponse aesPrimary = tpm.CreatePrimary(tpm._OwnerHandle, sensCreate, aesTemplate, nullVec, new TPMS_PCR_SELECTION[0]);
        TPM_HANDLE aesHandle = aesPrimary.handle;
        byte[] toEncrypt = new byte[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 12, 3, 4, 5};
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        EncryptDecryptResponse encrypted = tpm.EncryptDecrypt(aesHandle, (byte) 0, TPM_ALG_ID.CFB, iv, toEncrypt);
        EncryptDecryptResponse decrypted = tpm.EncryptDecrypt(aesHandle, (byte) 1, TPM_ALG_ID.CFB, iv, encrypted.outData);
        System.out.println("AES128 encryption with key = " + Helpers.toHex(aesKey));
        System.out.println("    Input     data:" + Helpers.toHex(toEncrypt));
        System.out.println("    encrypted data:" + Helpers.toHex(encrypted.outData));
        System.out.println("    decrypted data:" + Helpers.toHex(decrypted.outData));


        // persistent handle
        TPM_HANDLE persistentHandle = TPM_HANDLE.persistent(0x81010001);
        tpm.EvictControl(TPM_HANDLE.from(TPM_RH.OWNER), aesHandle, persistentHandle);
        if (!Helpers.arraysAreEqual(toEncrypt, decrypted.outData)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("encrypt/decrypt failed!");
        } else {
            tpm.FlushContext(aesHandle);
        }
        // clean object
        if (!Helpers.arraysAreEqual(toEncrypt, decrypted.outData)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("encrypt/decrypt failed!");
        } else {
            tpm.FlushContext(aesHandle);
        }
    }

Pom.xml dependency
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>TSS.Java</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

out put message:
AES128 encryption with key = 925255eb f0d30c3f 8de5abe5 196c01dd (16 bytes)
Input     data:01020304 05040302 0c030405 (12 bytes)
encrypted data:ba9ca20c a08c733d b3ee91ef (12 bytes)
decrypted data:01020304 05040302 0c030405 (12 bytes)
error message：
Exception in thread "main" tss.TpmException: Unexpected response tag {NO_SESSIONS}  
at tss.TpmBase.DispatchCommand(TpmBase.java:391)    
at tss.Tpm.EvictControl(Tpm.java:1930)  
at com.xxx.assist.XXXX.main(XXXX.java:12)

I have tried various methods that I am aware of, but have not been able to achieve good results, such as adding sessions, but still receive the message 'NO_SESSIONS'
byte[] nonceCaller = Helpers.RandomBytes(20); 
StartAuthSessionResponse policySession = tpm.StartAuthSession(TPM_HANDLE.NULL, TPM_HANDLE.NULL, nonceCaller, new byte[0], TPM_SE.POLICY, new TPMT_SYM_DEF(), TPM_ALG_ID.SHA1);

tpm.PolicyCommandCode(policySession.handle, TPM_CC.EvictControl);
tpm._withSession(policySession.handle).EvictControl(TPM_HANDLE.from(TPM_RH.OWNER), aesHandle,TPM_HANDLE.persistent(0x81010001));

